# Is there a way to check if a regular expression represents a url

Tags: java, regex, url

Is there a way to check whether a regular expression represents a valid URL ? Say, the regular expressions are Java Strings, is there a way to check whether these Strings represent a valid URL?

For e.g., say

```
String s1 = "/amazon\.com\//";
String s2 = "/google(\.[a-z]+)?\.[a-z]+\/search.*q=/i";
String s3 = "/.*/"; //Represents any URL
String s4 = "hello world";
```

s1, s2, and, s3 are valid regular expressions representing Urls but s4 is invalid.

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: Interesting.. if I understand the question correctly, you're asking to see if a regex matches a subset of another regex's matches...

Comment: Despite some browsers may or may not deal with _incomplete_ URIs/URLs, neither of your samples are valid by definition: `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id` with that said why not just creating the regex pattern to match whatever you consider as 'valid URL'?

Comment: How does thisroblem actually arise! Where are these regexes coming from? The user for example? And if so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to create a Regex that will match specific URLs, but it is next to impossible to write one that will match *any* valid URL, and also NOT match *any* invalid URLs.  For a start, you have to cope with percent encoding and the rules about when it can/should be used for different characters.

I should also point out that *none* of your examples is a valid URL according to the URL specifications.

---

My advice would be to use `new URL(String)` or `new URI(String)` to check for invalid URLs, and then examine the components to perform fine-grained matching.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should match any url (assuming thats your question, the wording is a bit cryptic):

```
String urlRegex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
String regexUrl = "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the post is asking how to determine if a given regular expression will match a valid URL.  Not whether those particular regex examples match a URL.

This could probably be generalized to determining if the language matched by a given regex can also be matched by a "canonical" regex that matches all URLs.  This previous question might be of some use:

[Does an algorithm exist which can determine whether one regular language matches any input another regular language matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630203/does-an-algorithm-exist-which-can-determine-whether-one-regular-language-matches)